# Can't login on deployed APS app, problem with authenticating

Tags: openshift, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have some trouble with the logging in to my APS Hubs Browser app after I have deployed it to OpenShift.

What I see when I try the app: type URL, get to the home screen, click login, we have SSO so it finds my mail an I only need to click 'Allow', when I click 'Allow' it return to the home screen. I have tried to do it in an incognito window, without SSO, but this ends in the same way.

After I click 'Allow' I get this error in the console:
[Console in deployed app after hitting 'Allow'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zCb0.png)

I am certain that the login credentials are identical for both on localhost and the deployed app.

I haven't encountered this problem while testing on localhost.

I believe the problem may have to do with either the AccessToken or RefreshToken not being added as a cookie, as sees on the picture under. 'session' and 'session.sig' are added locally but not in the deployed app. But I am unsure, since I also believe those are added after the 'Allow' button I clicked, and we don’t get pasted that step.
[Cookie overview of localhost app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAfYN.png)

Do you have any tips to how I can solve this? It would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have not used OpenShift before but I will try to help you.

Since your problem is occuring after deployment, can you check if the callback url in your app is set to match OpenShift URL as described at https://tutorials.autodesk.io/?check_logged_in=1#create-app-credentials

Comment: Good guess, but that is also pointing back to the OpenShift URL. Had som trouble with that earlier, resulting with an error right after clicking the 'login' button. So that's not the problem, unfortunately